# Find duplicate value and remove from select in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a code that find all the child node(within a same parent) and combine the value.

```
<xsl:template name="GetAllCompanys">
    <xsl:param name = "currZOFLFA1"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$currZOFLFA1/*:ZRTLFA1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="./*:BUKRS"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(', ', ./*:BUKRS)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

this code is working fine but now i have a requirement to perform an action to check **if there is a duplicate value among different parent then it should be skipped/remove**.
For example: I have an input xml like this

```
<DOC BEGIN="1">
<E1WYT3M SEGMENT="1">
    <ZOFLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <WERKS/>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0155</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0156</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0158</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0170</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
    </ZOFLFA1>
</E1WYT3M>
<E1WYT3M SEGMENT="1">
    <ZOFLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <WERKS>MA04</WERKS>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0155</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
    </ZOFLFA1>
</E1WYT3M>
<E1WYT3M SEGMENT="1">
    <ZOFLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
        <WERKS>MA05</WERKS>
        <ZRTLFA1 SEGMENT="1">
            <LIFN2>0010002493</LIFN2>
            <BUKRS>0156</BUKRS>
        </ZRTLFA1>
    </ZOFLFA1>
</E1WYT3M>
</DOC>
```

Based on my current code, for the first E1WYT3M element, it will be selecting the value from BUKRS and add it up which will return string "0155, 0156, 0158, 0170". 
 
 Now, i want to check are there same value from another E1WYT3M-BUKRS, if yes then it should be remove. 
Therefore,
the **expected result will be "0158, 0170"** as 0155 & 0156 is duplicated.

I have search a lot of discussion about how to find duplicate value but i have no idea how i should remove it while in select. Appreciate on any helps

Comment: Please (1) add the expected result to your question and (2) state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: XSLT version 2.0

Comment: Please try to get back to the answers you have received at some point.

Comment: Just try with your answer and making some modification on that. But i saw your answer had been removed and not able to make it "accept"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your current code can be simplified to:

```
<xsl:template name="GetAllCompanys">
    <xsl:param name = "currZOFLFA1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$currZOFLFA1/*:ZRTLFA1/*:BUKRS" separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
```

(Assuming the caller of the template doesn't mind getting the result back as a single text node rather than a sequence of text nodes).

Then, to remove duplicates, you can simply do:

```
<xsl:template name="GetAllCompanys">
    <xsl:param name = "currZOFLFA1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values($currZOFLFA1/*:ZRTLFA1/*:BUKRS)"
                  separator=", "/>
</xsl:template>
```

The `distinct-values()` function doesn't guarantee order of results; if that's a concern, you may want to use `xsl:for-each-group` instead.